# get record `id` before create/save | Sails Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am trying to create a notification for user.

with notification url in description like this `http://localhost:1337/invited/accept?referrer=msgIcon&id=this-notification-id` the url has id of this newly created notification.

```
  AppUserNotification.create({
    projectId: projectId,
    appuser: appusers.id,
    notificationTitle: 'You are invited in project',
    isRead: 0,
    description: 'You are invited in project collaboration, '
    + 'please accept invitation by following the link.\nHave a good day !\n'
    + 'Accept Invitation http://localhost:1337/invited/accept?referrer=msgIcon&id=this-notification-id',
  }).exec(function (err, appuserNotifications) {
    apiStatus = 1; // heading toward success
    if (err){
      return false;
    }else if(appuserNotifications){
      return true;
    }
  });//</after AppUserNotification.create()>
```

what I want to do is to save a link in description with this newly created notification. but couldn't manage to do so.
please help me.

Comment: You cant do that. Id comes from database so it is accessible only in callback. You can update it just after creation. ```appuserNotifications.description = 'your desc with id'; appuserNotifications.save()```

Answer (score 2):

By *default*, `id` is generated by database during record creating. So can be accessed only after creation.

Here are some ways in which your objective can be achieved:

1. **New attribute**: Add another unique attribute which is used in description URL. It can be generated randomly before creation (e.g. can use `UUID`)
2. **Use custom id**: Set `autoPK: false` in Model, generate `id` yourself; (I have done it for MySQL in `beforeCreate` hook using `UUID` as primary key `id`, not sure about MongoDB)
3. **Update after create**: Use `afterCreate` hook to update description with `id`
4. **New Model method**: Define a method say `getDescription()` in the Model which returns something like `this.description + this.id`.
5. **Override `toJSON()`**: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json

Comment: this is helpful, but looking for example describing get ID on create